# Do quantum teleportation require transmission media?

Tags: teleportation, communication, classical-communication

It said on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation):

> Because classical information needs to be sent, quantum teleportation cannot occur faster than the speed of light.

So does it mean quantum communication specifically teleportation still need transmission media like fiber optic, radio wave, coaxial cable, etc to implement classical channel / classical communication on quantum information (qubit state) teleportation?

But it also said, it doesn't need transmission media:

> The main advantage with this is that Bell states can be shared using photons from lasers making teleportation achievable through open space having no need to send information through physical cables or optical fibers.

If quantum teleportation still need classical channel then it must be need transmission media, in another word quantum teleportation is still hard to implement for massive long distance because it requires physical transmission media to carry classical bit such as radio wave or fiber optic. Or we can say, yes the qubit is teleported, but not for the classical bit (information) that will send to the receiver.

So is teleporting qubit in real quantum computer posible like teleporting a qubit from IBMQ_jakarta to IBMQ_belem?

Comment: Yes, teleporting quantum states within IBM Q processors is possible.

Comment: @MartinVesely Yes I know about teleporting IBM Q processors locally or in same IBM Q Computer/Circuit, but I'm asking teleporting between two IBM Q Computers. For example teleporting a qubit from IBM Q that located in jakarta to the IBM Q that located in belem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to describe quantum teleportation is in terms of how much information of each kind (classical or quantum) must be sent in which direction. If we have system $A$ (Alice) and system $B$ (Bob), then the "equation" for quantum teleporation basically looks like
\begin{equation}
1\text{ bell state } + 2\text{ cbits}_{A\rightarrow B} \Rightarrow 1 \text{ qbit}_{A\rightarrow B}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In other words, having shared entanglement and the ability to communicate two classical bits from Alice to Bob implies to the ability to transmit one qubit from Alice to Bob.

Alice just requires some way to communicate the values of two bits to Bob. This could be done by fiber optics, or satellite uplink, or carrier pigeon. It does not depend on *how* you send the bits, as long as the bits get sent.

Some choices of classical channel are noisier than others, and in this case your ability to faithfully transmit two bits might be reduced by errors in the communication channel. In this case, you might need to use your classical channel many times and implement some form of classical error correction to guarantee that the two classical bits were transmitted successfully. However this is purely a classical communication challenge - in this setting, Alice still only needed to consume one bell state in Eq. (1) to learn the initial two bits.

Comment: What do you mean one bell state? Is that come from one of a pair of qubit in entangled state?

Comment: Yes, we assume Alice and Bob are sharing a Bell state (or some other maximally entangled resource) of the form $(|0\rangle_A |0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_A |1\rangle_B)/\sqrt{2}$